# SUMIFS and ISFORMULA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This formula works

```
=SUMIF(KO1363:KR1363,">7")
```

But When I change SUMIF to SUMIFS and add in the ISFORMULA function I do not get the desired results.

```
=SUMIFS(KO1363:KR1363,KO1363:KR1363,">7",KO1363:KR1363,ISFORMULA(KO1363:KR1363)=TRUE)
```

I only want the SUMIFS to calculate cells which have formulas in them and a total over 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(KO1363:KR1363*(KO1363:KR1363>7)*ISFORMULA(KO1363:KR1363))
```

[image]